# Does the series $S^f$ to $f_n := \frac{n+1}{5n^2+n+2}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

So far I tried showing that $S^f$ < a geometric series, but with $\sum^\infty_{k=0} (\frac{1}{2})^n$ it doesn't work intuitively, because maybe the sequence elements are getting larger than the ones of the series. 
I tried showing that with induction but failed at a certain point, too.

One **Geometric** series:

$S^g = \sum^\infty_{k=0} 1 + \frac{1}{2} + < \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} ...$

**Given** series:

$S^f =\sum^\infty_{k=0}= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + < \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{12,5} ...$

I guess I could try it with larger geometric series but im unsure if thats a good approach.

Hints are very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given series is *divergent*.

**Hint**. One has, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
 \frac{n+1}{5n^2+n+2}\ge  \frac{n+1}{5n^2+5n}= \frac1{5n}
$$ giving, by comparison, the *divergence* of the initial series.

Comment: For future visitors: It's the "Direct comparision test/ criterion", also named "Majorantenkriterium" in german

Answer (score 1):

An important theorem about positive series such as $f_n$ says that if you can find another sequence $a_n$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f_n}{a_n}=L>0$$
then the series $\sum_n f_n$ and $\sum_n a_n$ have the same nature, that is, they either both converge or both diverge. Can you find such an $a_n$?

Comment: Pretty useful, do you know the name of the theorem?

Comment: Limit comparison test, apparently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: For future visitors: It's the "Ratio ´test/ Ratio criterion", also named "Quotientenkriterium" in german

Comment: I thought that the ratio test for a series was to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ as in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test.